# Error while matching a special character column of PostgreSQL 11.0 table

Tags: regex, postgresql

I am getting error while matching and replace a '-' character in one of my column values.
I have following PostgreSQL 11.0 table.

```
a      b
mp-6   mp 6
```

I am using following regex to match the two column values.

```
regexp_replace(a, '\-', ' ', 'g') ~* ('\y'||regexp_replace(b, '\-', ' ', 'g')||'\y')
```

I am getting following error:

```
[Code: 0, SQL State: 2201B]  ERROR: invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: The problem is not with the strings you posted, but some other strings. It may turn out, you can't use `\y` (if other records start/end with special chars) and it is clear you need to escape the `b` before using it as a regex pattern.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the string on the right hand side contains some characters that have a special meaning in regular expressions:

```
SELECT 'mama' ~* '+1';
ERROR:  invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid
```

Using an arbitrary string as regular expression is not only error-prone, but can be dangerous if a malicious attacker controls the strings. You could use `ILIKE` - that won't capture the beginning or end of a word, but perhaps it is good enough:

```
WHERE replace(a, '-', ' ') ILIKE
      '%' || replace(
                replace(
                   replace(
                      replace(b, '-', ' '),
                      '\', '\\'
                   ),
                   '_', '\_'
                ),
                '%', '\%
             ) || '%'
```

The additional `replace` escape the special characters in the pattern.